# ListView Filter Wrong Results

Tags: java, android, android-listview

This is a common problem but the resolved issues doesn't apply to my code so thought I'd paste my own code as I've noticed there is a million ways to accomplish the same results with Android Development which makes it a bit difficult but anyway...

Whenever I filter my listview, the position of the listview items is not maintained after the filter, the filtered items are assigned a new position starting from 0 therefore replacing the original listview item that was on position 0 with a new fileted item on that position.

eg: `listview = aONE [0], aTWO [1], aTHERE[2], bONE [3], b TWO[4], bTHREE [5].`

If I type "b" the new list is

`bONE [0], bTWO [1], bTHREE [2] and NOT bONE [3], bTWO [4], bTHREE [5],`

below is my code:

```
public class ListViewAdapterProduct extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ClassProductList> classProductlist = null;
    private ArrayList<ClassProductList> arraylist;

    public ListViewAdapterProduct(Context context, List<ClassProductList> classProductlist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.classProductlist = classProductlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ClassProductList>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(classProductlist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {        
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        ImageView photo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return classProductlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ClassProductList getItem(int position) {
        return classProductlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_single_row, null);
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textLarge);
            holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textSmall);
            holder.photo= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageThumb);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(classProductlist.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(classProductlist.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.photo.setImageResource(classProductlist.get(position).getImage());

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(position == 0) {
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(mContext, ProductMyactivity1.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent0);
                }

                if(position == 1) {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(mContext, ProductMyactivity2.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent1);
                }
            }        
        });

        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        classProductlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            classProductlist.addAll(arraylist);
        }
        else
        {
            for (ClassProductList Product : arraylist)
            {
                if (Product.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    classProductlist.add(Product);
                }
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following codes solved my issue in my ListViewAdapter

```
// Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            String mytitle=holder.listContent.getText().toString();

            if(mytitle.equals("murakoze")) {

                // Play song

                mp.reset();// stops any current playing song
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.murakoze);// create's
// new
// mediaplayer

// with
   // song.
                mp.start(); // starting mediaplayer

            }
        }
    });
    return view;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use another `itemId` but position in

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

By filtering the original items get moved to a "originalValues list", a new List is created and just filtered items put in it and displayed. All further calls to `getItem(int pos)` and many others work with the filtered list then. The position WILL change. You can implement your own ListView, or just use another id.

To do so in `getItemId(int pos)` call `ClassProductList getItem(int position)` to get your object. Retrieve your identifier from `ClassProductList` and use that one.

Comment: Explain in details please

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!!!!

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

String mytitle=holder.title.getText().toString();

if(mytitle.equals("ProductOne")){
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(mContext, ProductClass.ProductOne);
    mContext.startActivity(intent1);
    ...        
}
```

}

Had to add:

```
String mytitle=holder.title.getText().toString();
```

and use the string and NOT position, so no matter weather filter is applied or not, the list view item string is always used no matter which NEW position it takes on after filtering.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already set the adapter to your listview,there is an issue of get the current position of an item,so you have to firstly clear its content and then recall them

```
                lv.setAdapter( null );
                myData( );//contains your data
                ca.notifyDataSetChanged();//notifying the change
```

I think this is going to help you